# Proving property of recurrent classes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

To recall the basic set up, if we have a (time homogeneous) Markov Chain $X_n$, we say that states $i$ and $j$ communicate if there exist $n$ and $m$ such that $P_i(X_n=j)>0$ and $P_j(X_m=i)>0$. (Recall that $P_i$ is just the conditional probability measure on the event $X_0=i$; i.e., $P_i=P(\cdot\vert X_0=i)$.) Communication is an equivalence relation and partitions the state space into disjoint sets. We will call the elements of the partition classes.

Now, in a book on stochastic processes, they say that a class is transient if the M.C. starts in the class then eventually leaves and never returns with probability 1. Mathematically, a class $T$ is transient if $$P\left(\bigcup_{N\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge N} \{X_n\in T^c\}\,\vert\, X_0\in T\right)=1.$$ The states in the transient class are called transient states. They then define a recurrent class as a class that is not transient; i.e., $R$ is recurrent if $$P\left(\bigcup_{N\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge N} \{X_n\in R^c\}\,\vert\, X_0\in R\right)<1.$$
Again, the states of $R$ are called recurrent states.

I recognize that one usually defines the terms recurrent and transient in a slightly different way; i.e., usually one starts by defining recurrent and transient states, opposed to the classes. And, furthermore, the definition usually is stated with the probability that a state returns to itself in finite time, opposed to whether the chain stays in the class. However, I would like to work with the definition I provided. (Unless of course something is wrong, in which case I would like a correct definition in terms of classes.)

I would like to prove some familiar things about recurrent classes. For example, I would like to prove the following:

(i) If $R$ is recurrent then $P\left(\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\{X_n\in R\}\,\vert\, X_0\in R\right)=1$, i.e. if the chain starts in $R$ then it never leaves with probability $1$.

(ii) If $R$ is recurrent then $P\left(\bigcap_{N\ge 1}\bigcup_{n\ge N}\{X_n=i\}\,\vert\, X_0=i\right)=1$ for all $i\in R$, i.e. the chain will return to $i$ infinitely often if it starts at $i$.

I wasn't having too much luck myself trying to rigorously prove these using the definitions of transient and recurrent classes that I provided. Would appreciate help to proving these.

Comment: Is the state space of the Markov chain a countable set?  Am I right to assume the time variable is discrete (i.e. a non-negative integer)?

Comment: @fourierwho yes, countable state space.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what textbook does this definition come from?

Comment: @Wraith1995 Comes from page 20 of Introduction to Stochastic Processes by Greg Lawler. At this point in the book he is dealing with finite state spaces. The definition is kind of informally stated. Perhaps he provides the more standard definition later when dealing with more arbitrary (countable?) state spaces. I just wanted to know how (or if) this definition and the standard definition are equivalent (and how to derive some familiar results from this). Note: the definition he gives is just written out in (informal) English. I converted it to a rigorous form in terms of probabilities.

Comment: @Atsana I actually own that book. He gives another definition on page 45, but it is not that much more rigorous. You might want to take a look at how he uses it. I would rephrase his definition of recurrence as $P(\bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n} \{X_{n}\in R\} \mid X_{0}\in R) = 1$. I do not think this is equivalent to your definition, but I'm just eyeballing it. You seem to have written that a state space is recurrent if with probability less than one the chain is outside of it for all but finitely many $n$.